# String reformatting with levels , I am stuck

Tags: string, r

I have below string that needs to be reformatted

```
"itemStockDetailsMap_506540 = {\"506540_Navy\":{\"24DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"18DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"16DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"8DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"20DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"10DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"12DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"22DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"14DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2}},
\"506540_Mocha\":{\"20DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"22DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"10DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"8DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"12DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"14DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"16DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"24DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"18DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2}}
,\"506540_Grey\":{\"18DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"12DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"10DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"20DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"14DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"22DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"24DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"16DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2},\"8DUMMY\":{\"count\":0.0,\"type\":2}}}"
```

I want to represent it in

```
colour  size   count
Navy    18     0.0
Navy     8     0.0
......
Grey     10    0.0
```

........

Please guide me me if there are any cool tricks to get this reformatted ..
Many Thanks,

Comment: Where did these data come from? It's almost JSON, for which there are several packages you can *easily* use to convert to some reasonable data structure. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: There might be a way to do this with one line using a regular expression.  However, perhaps first remove all text through the `=`, then sequentially remove the text `DUMMY` and `count` and `:\"` and `{` and `}}}` then split on `,`.  Something like that might work.  But you should really show what you tried.

Comment: @MarkMiller, no need for regex here.  just `rjson::fromJSON(x)`

Comment: I have tried to extract string using ":{" "}"  str_extract_all(stock,"\\:\\{(.*?)\\}") .I am not aware of packages JSON , can you please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your string is in variable `a`:

```
require(rjson)
a <- sub(".*?(\\{.*\\})", "\\1", a)
a <- fromJSON(a)
a <- do.call(rbind, a)
cbind.data.frame(
  colour = rep(sub("\\d+_(\\w+)", "\\1", rownames(a)), each=dim(a)[2]),
  size = as.numeric(rep(sub("(\\d+)\\w+", "\\1", colnames(a)), dim(a)[1])), 
  count = as.numeric(unname(unlist(sapply(a, "[", "count")))))
#    colour size count
# 1    Navy   24     2
# 2    Navy   18     1
# 3    Navy   16     0
# 4    Navy    8     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
install.packages("rjson")

 # 'yourData' is the JSON string in the OP
 do.call(rbind, lapply(rjson::fromJSON(yourData), function(xx) do.call(rbind, xx)))

        count type
24DUMMY 0     2   
18DUMMY 0     2   
16DUMMY 0     2   
8DUMMY  0     2   
20DUMMY 0     2   
10DUMMY 0     2   
12DUMMY 0     2   
22DUMMY 0     2   
14DUMMY 0     2   
20DUMMY 0     2   
22DUMMY 0     2   
10DUMMY 0     2   
8DUMMY  0     2   
12DUMMY 0     2   
14DUMMY 0     2   
16DUMMY 0     2   
24DUMMY 0     2   
18DUMMY 0     2   
18DUMMY 0     2   
12DUMMY 0     2   
10DUMMY 0     2   
20DUMMY 0     2   
14DUMMY 0     2   
22DUMMY 0     2   
24DUMMY 0     2   
16DUMMY 0     2   
8DUMMY  0     2
```

Comment: Thank you all for the guidance.